# weird error message using ggsave /sprintf

Tags: r, ggplot2, save, printf, bounds

I am calculating residuals from many regressions to plot these residuals afterwards with ggplot.

I took the 6 variables of interest from my datafile and created the subfieldsdata file (6 columns, 116 rows).

The linear regression models:

```
buildres <- sapply(seq_along(subfieldsdata), function(i) lm(subfieldsdata[,i] ~ myData$NP_Age+myData$sex+myData$YrsOfEd), simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)
```

Calculation of the residuals:

```
getres <- vapply(buildres, stdres, numeric(116))
```

Adding column names:

```
colnames(getres) <- c("Subiculum residuals", "Presubiculum residuals", "CA1 residuals", "CA3 residuals", "CA4 residuals", "Dentate gyrus residuals")
```

Then I have a for loop for ggplot:

```
for (i in 1:ncol (getres)) {
gp <- ggplot(data=subfieldsdata,aes(x=ECtau.res,y=getres[,i])) + geom_point(colour="Blue", shape=17, size=5)
gp <- gp +
stat_smooth(method="lm", colour="Blue", size=2, fill="Blue") +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, max(getres[,i])*1.1, 0.5)) +
theme_grey(base_size=35) +
labs(x="EC tau residuals", y=colnames(getres)[i]))
 print (gp)
ggsave(sprintf("ECtau%s.png", colnames((getres)[i]),gp))
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error in strsplit(filename, "\\.")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I cannot be the dimensions:

```
dim(getres)
[1] 116   6
```

I also checked the colnames:

```
> colnames(getres)
[1] "Subiculum residuals"     "Presubiculum residuals"  "CA1 residuals"           "CA3 residuals"          
[5] "CA4 residuals"           "Dentate gyrus residuals"
```

Do you know what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to guess what may be the error without a reproducible example but I'm guessing that the output from *sprintf* is the problem. Just to see what's going on, did you try creating the desired file name outside the *ggsave*?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer Heidi?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Heidi :)

This (your plot with some fake data and a temp variable for the file name) works fine for me:

```
# Weird Error Message

ncol <- 6
nrow <- 116
subfieldsdata <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol))
colnames(subfieldsdata)[1] <- "ECtau.res"

getres <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol))
colnames(getres) <- c("Subiculum residuals", "Presubiculum residuals",
                      "CA1 residuals", "CA3 residuals", 
                      "CA4 residuals", "Dentate gyrus residuals")

for (i in 1:ncol (getres)) {
  gp <- ggplot(data=subfieldsdata,aes(x=ECtau.res,y=getres[,i])) + 
        geom_point(colour="Blue", shape=17, size=5)
  gp <- gp +
    stat_smooth(method="lm", colour="Blue", size=2, fill="Blue") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4, max(getres[,i])*1.1, 0.5)) +
    theme_grey(base_size=35) +
    labs(x="EC tau residuals", y=colnames(getres)[i])
  print (gp)
  fname <- sprintf("ECtau%s.png", colnames((getres)[i]))
  print(sprintf("Saving %s ",fname))
  ggsave(fname,gp)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "Saving ECtauSubiculum residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
[1] "Saving ECtauPresubiculum residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
[1] "Saving ECtauCA1 residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
[1] "Saving ECtauCA3 residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
[1] "Saving ECtauCA4 residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
[1] "Saving ECtauDentate gyrus residuals.png "
Saving 7.62 x 7.11 in image
>
```

The last plot:

[image]

And their was a typo in your code (one too many parenthesis on the labs argument), so I am thinking that this is maybe not an exact duplicate of your problem code. Clearly the problem is in your filename, something is going wrong with that filename, which is why I printed it out.

I would suggest printing out the filename and seeing what went wrong.

Now that I think of it, another guess is that you have some periods (that is "." characters) in the column names of your `subfieldsdata` dataframe that are confusing the `ggsave` routine. This is probably the problem - try using dashes or something instead.

Also take this as a lesson in how to create a properly reproducible question. :)